# Transpiling from ecma6 to ecma5 in Aurelia not working

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, aurelia, transpiler

Does anyone have experience with transpiling from ecma6 to ecma5  in the aurealia tutorials?

I am doing the production tutorial found here http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.4/doc/article/a-production-setup

When running the gulp task 'build-e2e' it takes the files in the test/e2e/src directory and spits out a version in the test/e2e/dist directory. Great but the files are the same (it picks up changes but seems to transpile from ecma6 to ecma6.

**EDIT**
When running 'gulp e2e' I get the following log messages: [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
FFFF

Failures:

1) Exception loading: /......../aurelia-production-tutorial/test/e2e/dist/demo.spec-compiled.js Error
   Message:
     SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
   Stacktrace:
     SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object. (/........./aurelia-production-tutorial/test/e2e/dist/demo.spec-compiled.js:3:20)

Comment: We're going to need some more details of your code to help figure out what's breaking for you. Could you push your code to a GitHub repo?

Comment: @AshleyGrant The code is the default code found on the aurelia website http://aurelia.io/downloads/kit-es2016.zip  The step that goes wrong is found here http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.4/doc/article/a-production-setup under section 'Running The E2E Tests'. I've added some log messages to the question description.

Comment: @AshleyGrant It looks like it spists out compiled and non compiled versions in the dist folder.